# Is there a general method for calculating expectation values for time-dependent wavefunctions?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, hamiltonian

Is there a general method for calculating expectation value? I have a workshop question, and I'm sure what a good process to follow is. It is given that $$|\psi(t = 0)\rangle = |0\rangle\,,\tag{1}$$ and we need to find the expectation value of the Pauli $X$ matrix. I've seen suggestions online to start with the Schrodinger equation to find the time evolution of a quantum state.

Where should I go next?

Comment: "Is there a general method for calculating expectation value?" If by "general" you mean "at any time $t$" then you must solve the schrodinger equation. The time-dependent schrodinger equation is **the** equation that tells you how the system evolves in time. There's no other way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I won't give the final answer (close to it), but instead try and point you in the general direction.

1. **Initial State**: The given initial state is $ | \psi(t=0) \rangle = | 0 \rangle $.
2. **Pauli X Matrix**: The Pauli X matrix is defined as
   $
      \sigma_x = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
      $
3. **Expectation Value a**: The expectation value of an operator $ \hat{O} $ in a state $| \psi \rangle$ given by
   $$
      \langle \hat{O} \rangle = \langle \psi | \hat{O} | \psi \rangle
      $$
   In this case, $\hat{O}$ is the Pauli $X$ matrix and $ | \psi \rangle $ is $ | 0 \rangle $.
4. **Calculation**:
   So, to find the expectation value of $ \sigma_x $ for the state $ | 0 \rangle $, we compute
   $$
      \langle \sigma_x \rangle = \langle 0 | \sigma_x | 0 \rangle = \dots
      $$
   and the answer should follow easily from here. If you're unsure how to calculate the inner product (or matrix multiplication in general), have a look [here](https://mathforquantum.quantumtinkerer.tudelft.nl/4_vector_spaces_QM/).

**Addition:**

For the original (now editied question), you're asked to find $\langle\psi(t)|\sigma_x|\psi(t)\rangle$. For this, the state at time $t$ is obtained by applying the time evolution operator $e^{-iHt/\hbar}$ to the initial state. Thus, you'll need to calculate,
$$
   |\psi(t)\rangle = e^{-iHt/\hbar} |\psi(t=0)\rangle.
   $$